# How to store a list to Firestore and fetch it in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The data I want to store looks like this

```
Class(
      id: '0',
      title: 'Yoga (Beginner)',
      categories: ['1', '2'],
      length: '30',
      displayImage: './assets/images/yoga.png'),
)
```

but I have no idea how to **store the categories list** to Firestore, should I store it as a collection or normal field?

I have the below code to fetch the class information

```dart
class DataService {
  final Firestore _db = Firestore.instance;

  Stream<List<Class>> getClassesSnapshot() {
    try {
      var snaps = _db.collection('classes').snapshots();
      snaps.handleError((e) {
        print(e);
        return Stream.empty();
      });

      return snaps.map(
          (list) => list.documents.map((doc) => Class.fromSnap(doc)).toList());
    } catch (e) {
      return Stream.empty();
    }
  }
}

factory Class.fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot classSnap) {
    return Class(
      id: classSnap.data['id'],
      title: classSnap.data['title'],
      categories: classSnap.data['categories'],
      length: classSnap.data['length'],
      displayImage: classSnap.data['imageUrl'],
    );
  }
```

but it seems Firestore doesn't support "list" and it stopped at the categories field.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Your `categories` looks like an array field in the `Class` document to me. What's the problem you have with storing it? So: if you run it in a debugger, what line of hthe code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks Frank for always helping. I just tried store the categories as a array to Firestore. When I run the code `snaps.map(
          (list) => list.documents.map((doc) => Class.fromSnap(doc)).toList());` and `categories: classSnap.data['classCategories'],`
It gets null, it seems dart doesn't recognise that is a list of string

Comment: [Screenshot](https://snipboard.io/7xBCsL.jpg) What the IDE shows for classSnap.data. if I `print (classSnap.data['categories'])` it shows [1, 2]

Comment: It looks like you've made good progress there Ennis. What's the problem with the code as you have it now?

Comment: Thanks Frank! The problem is it seems classSnap.data['categories'] return a List of some data type instead of a List of String. [Firestore screenshot](https://snipboard.io/QzDLEM.jpg)

Comment: Kinda weird to me.
I use a for loop to create a List<String> out of `classSnap.data['categories']` It works!
The data was stored as a String inside a Array in Firestore.